# Error while binding data templates for switching user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and struggling with a binding for many days. I'm trying to switch the user controls on click of menuitems, using data templates with data type of the view models

Data Templates :-

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AppleViewModel}">
    <views:AppleView/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MangoViewModel}">
    <views:MangoView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The binding of property has been done in the content control :-

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

BaseViewModel.cs inherited from ObservableObject (using MVVM ToolKit) :-

I tried by assigning the typeof ViewModel, new ViewModel etc as follows,

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    public object? currentViewModel;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Navigate(string menu)
    {
        switch (menu)
        {
            case "Apple":
                CurrentViewModel = (typeof(AppleViewModel));
                break;
            case "Mango":
                CurrentViewModel = new MangoViewModel();
                break;
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error and the content is not changing as per the data template.

[image]

Error message 1:  Failed to convert value 'XYTool.ViewModels.MangoViewModel' (type 'MangoViewModel') to the target type using converter 'ObjectSourceConverter'. The fallback value will be used if it's available. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from XYTool.ViewModels.MangoViewModel.

Error message 2:  Cannot convert 'XYTool.ViewModels.MangoViewModel' from type 'MangoViewModel' to type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from XYTool.ViewModels.MangoViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

you should create intances of view models, assigning their type won't make them appear:

```
[ObservableProperty]
public object? currentViewModel;

[RelayCommand]
private void Navigate(string menu)
{
    switch (menu)
    {
        case "Apple":
            CurrentViewModel = new AppleViewModel();
            break;
        case "Mango":
            CurrentViewModel = new MangoViewModel();
            break;
    }
}
```

and then in xaml bind only Content. default ContentTemplate will be found for Content type:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried this and all I can see in the content is the object name getting displayed Eg: XYTool.ViewModels.MangoViewModel. For testing, I directly bind the data template as a static resource using a key, and the view loads perfectly. But not sure why the binding is not working properly :(

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should understand what the properties of `ContentControl` do. `Content` is **what** is displayed (think view model) and `ContentTemplate` is **how** it is displayed (think view).

Option 1:

Write your `ContentControl` bindings like this

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

and make sure that the `DataTemplate`s are defined in the same file, not in an external resource dictionary.

Option 2:

You can define a `ContentTemplateSelector` like this:

```
public class FruitTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate AppleTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate MangoTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return item switch
        {
            AppleViewModel => AppleTemplate,
            MangoViewModel => MangoTemplate,
            _ => base.SelectTemplate(item, container)
        };
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
        <local:FruitTemplateSelector>
            <local:FruitTemplateSelector.AppleTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AppleViewModel}">
                    <views:AppleView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:FruitTemplateSelector.AppleTemplate>
            <local:FruitTemplateSelector.MangoTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MangoViewModel}">
                    <views:MangoView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:FruitTemplateSelector.MangoTemplate>
        </local:FruitTemplateSelector>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Option 2 is pointless here because you would only use it when you want to select different DataTemplates for data items of the same type. Besides that, it is incorrect that the DataTemplates have to be "*defined in the same file*". They only need to be accessible from the current scope, but could as well be defined in a ResourceDictionary somewhere up in the visual or logical tree, e.g. in Application.Resources.